# What next, after Pistol Squats

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises, legs

I perform body-weight exercises and so far had something to progress to without requiring weights. I am now able to do 8-12 reps of Pistol Squats. To strengthen my legs further is there any other more challenging form of leg exercises that I can do without using weights, or have I reached the limit of body-weights in my case?

Comment: Pilates side leg for high reps, lunges, doing pistol squats from rest at the bottom, standing calf raises at a 100 reps, box jumps etc. You can always increase the reps to make these exercises even more challenging.

Comment: @mobcityzkore Doesn't increasing reps increase endurance as opposed to strength?

Comment: You haven't reached the 'limit' of body-weights. If you have access to weights, I suggest you hit them but if not, increasing reps and doing the other exercises I mentioned will benefit you nonetheless. Yeah, there's an aspect of endurance training but even that will result in some hypertrophy (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18787090). 'Strengthen' your legs is inducing hypertrophy. If by strengthen you mean push more weight, strength is largely neural and to increase that weight pushing strength, you have to push weight (i.e. back squat, deadlift, linear progression etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently Shrimp Squat and Advanced Shrimp Squat seems to be more difficult that Pistol Squats.

Comment: While you are certainly free to write and accept your own answer, this doesn't really answer your own question. Just because a squat may be described as more difficult, it doesn't necessarily mean they are the ones you should do next.

Answer (score 4):

You can always increase the time you are doing the exercise, increasing the *time under tension*. In addition to it, you can also do the same exercises with "holds". For example, you can stay in pistol squat deep position for 15 seconds, and do 8-12 reps afterwards, it will be harder to do.